# NgClass Chats for both receive and sender while displaying the chats in alternative manner

Tags: html, angular, performance, angular-ui-bootstrap

If I receive a msg my profile picture and message should be on left and If I send a msg my profile picture and message should be on right. How can I do that using this function ? or can someone shows me the changes ?

```
<div *ngFor="let message of allfinanceMsg" class="pb-4">
  <div [ngClass]="(message.MESSAGE_FROM === 'FINANCE') ? 'send-content' : 'receive-content'" class="col-md-12 d-flex"> {{message.MESSAGE}}
    <p [ngClass]="(message.MESSAGE_FROM === 'USER') ? 'send-date' : 'receive-date'" class="d-flex col-md-12"> {{message.CREATED_DATE | date : 'EEE MMM dd, h:mm a'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's your CSS in 'receive-content' and 'send-content' ? Your logic is correct. But it looks like your CSS is wrong. Please post it in the question.

Comment: share your css as well